# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. Secondary error

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**

I am trying to complete a simple query.

I have a `Staging` database that I have imported some text data into. I am now trying to move this new data into my main database.

I initially had an error of:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_factSales_dimDistrict". The conflict occurred in database "SalesStarAssignment", table "dbo.dimDistrict", column 'DistrictID'

I found the answer to this and I have now moved onto this error.

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition (there is another 'question' posed but does not help me as such. Or at least I cannot apply it to my issue?)

In the INSERT table I have the following columns:

- DistrictID (PK)(int)
- District (nvarchar50)
- City (nvarchar50)
- Postcode (nvarchar50)
- Type (nvarchar50)
- CountyID (FK) (int)
- Quantity (Float)
- Date (date)
- CustomerID (int)
- ProductID (int)
- Value (money)
- BranchID (int)

In the SELECT table I have the following columns:

- DistrictID (int)
- Quantity (Float)
- Date (date)
- CustomerID (int)
- ProductID (int)
- Value (money)
- BranchID (int)

There are 28 new data rows to go across.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and (1) tag with the database you are using; (2) should your `insert` statement.

Comment: Done that, any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting a new row in the table `dimDistrict`, 
so the 1st you need to check is if the value for the primary key column `DistrictID` is not a duplicate. 
If this is not the case then, check if you **must supply a value** for the column `CountyID` which holds a reference to another table.
Of course you should already have checked this

> FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_factSales_dimDistrict"

in your database to see what it is all about.

Answer (score 1):

For your second issue, the error message says that you are inserting different number of fields than the destination table. To ensure you fix correctly the issue use the format:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable (field1, field2, ..., fieldn)
SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldn)
FROM SourceTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

DistrictID is a primary key.

If it's an [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) then it would be auto-generated. And then you wouldn't need to insert it.

But if it's not autogenerated, then you can't insert duplicate DistrictID in it.
Since it's a primary key and that has to be unique in the table.

In the INSERT statement you should also list the columns you insert from the select.
In the same order.

**For example:**

```
INSERT INTO YourDestinationTable 
      (DistrictID, Quantity, [Date], CustomerID, ProductID, [Value], BranchID)
SELECT DistrictID, Quantity, [Date], CustomerID, ProductID, [Value], BranchID
FROM YourOriginTable orig
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM YourDestinationTable dest
  WHERE dest.DistrictID = orig.DistrictID
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. this is the new error from that. 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DistrictID', table 'SalesStarAssignment.dbo.dimDistrict'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.'

Comment: @AaronBurton Then I guess it's not setup as an [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property). But it's a Primary Key, so you can't insert duplicate DistrictID  in it.  Is it an empty table?

Comment: no it has values. And yes it is set as a primary key into a 'FACTSTABLE'.

Comment: Shouldn't you also insert that "District" varchar? The name of the district seems rather usefull for that destination table?